# DataGridView Row ForeColor not changing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a method which loops through each row within my `DataGridView` and assigns the required `ForeColor` however am not sure as to why my `DataGridView` is not accepting these styles? Here is the code which handles this

```
Private Shared Sub dgvRowFormatting(dgv As DataGridView) 
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows            
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = lColor
    Next
End Sub
```

I pass the method once I assign `BindingSource` to the `DataGridView DataSource` as follows:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = customerList
dgv.DataSource = bindingSource
dgvRowFormatting(dgv)
```

I am not really sure if I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating either cells or rows and setting a style property based on a condition is not advisable as it wastes resources and you must call your styling method each time a single value changes to ensure proper styling.

It is better to use the [CellFormatting Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2) to perform this customization.

To demonstrate, the following is a simple example that conditionally sets the ForeColor based on even/odd row index.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If (e.RowIndex And 1) = 1 Then
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red ' odd numbered row
    Else
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black ' even numbered rows
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this example could be also be accomplished using the [DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2) if the conditon is only alternating rows.

For more guidance, see: [Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Comment: Ended up using CellFormatting Event in the end. Worked well :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify the [RowsDefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsdefaultcellstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), before or after setting the `DataSource`.
No needed to set the `DefaultCellStyle` of each Row:

```
dgv.DataSource = bindingSource
dgv.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = lColor
```

If you want to set this values on **alternating** Rows, use the [AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) property:

```
dgv.DataSource = bindingSource
dgv.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = lColor
```

If you want to change all the Rows' Cells to a different `ForeColor` based on some conditions, you need to specify these conditions somewhere.

**Example of conditional setter for a Color property**:
A custom class comparer used to change the `ForeColor` of the `Cells` of each `Row` to a different value, based on some pre-defined conditions: a `([Column], [Row]).Value` is less/equal/greater than zero.

```
Private Shared Sub dgvRowFormatting(dgv As DataGridView)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        Dim CompareValue = Convert.ToInt32(dgv(1, row.Index).Value)
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = MyConditions.SetCondition(CompareValue)
    Next
End Sub

Public Class MyConditions
    Public Enum Condition
        LessThanZero = -1
        EqualToZero
        GreaterThanZero
    End Enum

    Public Shared Function SetCondition(Of T As IComparable)(ByVal Value As T) As Color
        Return SetColorOnCondition(CType(Value.CompareTo(0), Condition))
    End Function

    Private Shared Function SetColorOnCondition(Comparison As Condition) As Color
        Select Case Comparison
            Case Condition.LessThanZero
                Return Color.Red
            Case Condition.EqualToZero
                Return Color.Black
            Case Condition.GreaterThanZero
                Return Color.Green
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry @Jimmi each row had a different `ForeColor` according to condition which in this case is passed via the Global variable `lColor`

Comment: `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows` <- This sets the same ForeColor to all the Rows. Can you explain in more details what your requirements are?

Comment: No idea. Have you checked whether the `lColor` value is actually set? If it's not (null), the loop may be just aborted. Or the value may be equal to the original Color. But I don't know what `lColor` is. Btw, it should be a parmeter of the `dgvRowFormatting` method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do the things in other ways (See @Jimi's or @TnTinMn's posts).

But your code works fine. The only thing is to change the **lColor** to a correct color, for example: **Color.Red**

Before run it, just ensure you have some data populated in the datagridview.

You should see red text in the gridview.

```
Private Shared Sub dgvRowFormatting(dgv As DataGridView)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: 2018-11-14 17:45

Of course all the text is red. Note that we don't know your conditions to change the color.

Here you have an example of your code changing the color based on the column ID value:

```
Private Shared Sub dgvRowFormatting(dgv As DataGridView)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        Select Case row.Cells("Id").Value
            Case 1, 2
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Case 3, 4
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            Case Else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jortx unfortunately the above code doesn't seem to work :( It just seems to set the entire rows the same color

Comment: @Jimi I already have condition which sets what color will be each row which gets set to `lColor`

Comment: But your code sets **all** the Rows Cells ForeColor. Not just some of them.